# CSS styling jQuery's 'selectmenu' plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Selectmenu: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

I'm using this plugin to style a select menu on a widget I'm building. I have all the functionality working correctly but I can't seem to style the list items it generates. The text is wrapped inside an anchor tag inside the #wrap div it creates at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector should work

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu li a { *your styling here* }
```

Comment: This will affect all select menus. Would be great if we could style a specific select menu.

Comment: you can add id of selectmenu to css selector. 
#fakeId.ui-selectmenu-menu li a { *your styling here* }

Answer (score 0):

@smegger's answer shows how to style all drop downs.
If you want to style a specific one it will not work to wrap the select with a given class since the dropdown html is created right above the closing body tag. Therefor you need to add an ID attribute to the select tag

```
<select id="some_id" name="some_name">...options...</select>
```

This will create the ul dropdown html tag with an ID of `'some_id-menu'`

In order to style it just use:

```
#some_id-menu li a { *your styling here* }
```